# How to pass List through viewmodel with cshtml without database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list, viewmodel

I am working on a webapplication where u can keep stock of what you have in your shop. But when I hit submit, the previous list doesn`t show up in the submitted form.

Everything else of the information is in the viewmodel.

Any help is welcome

Here is my code

INDEX.CSHTML

```
@{
ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

@model WebApp.Models.Item;

<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Stock manager</h1>
    <form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="AddItem" method="post">
        <label>Naam</label>
        <input type="text" asp-for="Name" name="Name" />
        <label>Aantal</label>
        <input type="number" asp-for="Aantal" name="Aantal" />
        <label>Beschrijving</label>
        <input type="text" asp-for="Beschrijving" name="Beschrijving" />
        <input type="submit" value="toevoegen" />

        <h1 class="display-4">Stock list</h1>
        @if (Model.Stock != null)
        {
    <ul>
        @for (int idx = 0; idx < Model.Stock.Count; idx++)
        {
            <li>
                @Html.HiddenFor(Model.Stock[idx].Name)
                @Html.HiddenFor(Model.Stock[idx].Aantal)
                @Html.HiddenFor(Model.Stock[idx].Beschrijving)
                <h3>@Model.Stock[idx].Name</h3>
                <p>Aantal: @Model.Stock[idx].Aantal</p>
                <p>Beschrijving: @Model.Stock[idx].Beschrijving</p>
            </li>

        }
    </ul>
        }
        else
        {
            <span>Nog niets toegevoegd</span>
        }
    </form>
</div>
```

HOMECONTROLLER.CS

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using WebApp.Models;

namespace WebApp.Controllers
{
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
    public  List<Item> items;
    public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;

    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        Item item = new Item();
        return View(item);
    }


    public IActionResult AddItem(Item item)
    {
        if (item.Stock == null)
        {
            item.Stock = new List<Item>();
        }

        item.Stock.Add(new Item
        {
            Name = item.Name,
            Aantal = item.Aantal,
            Beschrijving = item.Beschrijving
        });

        return View("Index",item);
    }

    [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
    public IActionResult Error()
    {
        return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
    }
}
}
```

ITEM.CS

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebApp.Models
{
public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Aantal { get; set; }
    public string Beschrijving { get; set; }
    public List<Item> Stock { get; set; }
}
}
```

This is a schoolproject due to the end of the weekend so i'm kinda worried plus there is some unit testing still to do.

Thank you!

RAW HTML after adding 2 items

```
 <div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Stock manager</h1>
    <form method="post" action="/Home/AddItem">
        <label>Naam</label>
        <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" value="test" />
        <label>Aantal</label>
        <input type="number" name="Aantal" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Aantal field is required." id="Aantal" value="3" />
        <label>Beschrijving</label>
        <input type="text" name="Beschrijving" id="Beschrijving" value="test" />
        <input type="submit" value="toevoegen" />

        <h1 class="display-4">Stock list</h1>
            <ul>
                    <li>
                        <h3>test</h3>
                        <p>Aantal: 3</p>
                        <p>Beschrijving: test</p>
                    </li>
            </ul>
    <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="CfDJ8KvM1zMUD4ZOqfaYG4a2bsBumYriiijPssoEk30unaH30LZcWhGlluH47isCWUR2P-tDvQNQWZgxgHJRhqHf_2SyfcRI80clCL3fvM0hETtZ43eiWokSS3vId3OQe-P8rP1jBe5RWYyt8n9UB9yPjaI" /></form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a for loop rather than foreach and index your list items like so...

```
<ul>
@for (int idx = 0; idx < Model.Stock.Count; idx++) {
    <li>
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.Stock[idx].Name)
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.Stock[idx].Aantal)
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.Stock[idx].Beschrijving)
                <h3>Model.Stock[idx].Name</h3>
                <p>Aantal: Model.Stock[idx].Aantal</p>
                <p>Beschrijving: Model.Stock[idx].Beschrijving</p>
    </li>

}
</ul>
```

Comment: I`m sorry but that doesn't fix it

Comment: Sorry I missed the fact that you'd not wrapped your form element around the list either!

Comment: Wrapped the form around the list and that still doesn't fix it

Comment: You don't see the List when you hit AddItem at controller? Can you show me the HTML generated for the list on your page?

Comment: The list is visible but when i click to  add a new item it changes the value of the 1 item in the list and the old one is gone

Comment: So my question is how do I make sure the previous list is in the Model.Stock when i hit submit in the form

Comment: I wanted to see the raw HTML generated when you view it in the browser - this would help understand why its null.

Comment: I've updated my example to include the hidden elements for binding back to stock list on POST.

Comment: Error CS7036 There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'htmlAttributes' of 'IHtmlHelper<Item>.HiddenFor<TResult>(Expression<Func<Item, TResult>>, object)'

Comment: Post up what your view looks like now and I’ll see if I can spot the problem

Comment: Updated the CSHTML in the post

Comment: I’m afraid I don’t see a problem, this is exactly how I always bind my lists.

Comment: I found it, it had to be like this @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.Stock[idx].Name)

Answer (score 0):

When you call index, you are instantiating a new Item obj which is why you don't see your previous added item. Change it to something like:

```
public Item item; 

public IActionResult Index()
    {
        if(item == null)
       {
         Item item = new Item();
         return View(item);
       }
       return View(item);
    }
```

Comment: In that way there is no previous item to check if null

Comment: I think linkedlistt is correct, when looking at the code posted Index does indeed create a new instance of item so calling Index from AddItem you will cause you to lose your data.  Put a break point in AddItem to check whether your data has been passed as expected.

Comment: Everything is passed correctly just the Stock is null everytime